# Updating CMDIChildWnd title in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using SetWindowText() of CMDIChildWnd from CScrollView for setting the title from , when I open a document. But title did not get updated, untill I click on the image or when I minimize the application.

I have tried with calling Invalidate(), UpdateWindow() but none of these are working, but I anyhow need to update the title.

Can anyone please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Call the documents SetTitle() method with the title you want. SetTitle() will call CDocument::UpdateFrameCounts(), UpdateFrameCounts() will call the CMDIChildWnd::OnUpdateFrameTitle(TRUE) which will update your frame.

I would think SetWindowText() would work, but it might be that OnUpdateFrameTitle() is getting called afterwards because of UI updating or something, and that OnUpdateFrameTitle() is setting the title back to what it was. Try a breakpoint in CMDIWHildWnd::OnUpdateFrameTItle() or in the CMDIFrameWnd version as well.

Comment: CFrameWnd also has a `SetTitle` method, I wonder what the difference is?

Comment: I had tried with SetTitle() and in that case I am only getting document title every time. And by calling SetWindowText() I get the title what I am passing to it, not the default document name.

I am getting the title what I passed to SetWindowText() but I shows only when I click inside the document, But my requirement is not set the title, at the moment the document get open.